# After completing a blacklist race is there a way to guarantee a pink slip reward from the opposing driver?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

After defeating Need For Speed: Most Wanted (2005)'s difficult [Blacklist](https://nfs.fandom.com/wiki/Blacklist) drivers you are given the option to pick two of three available [Reward Markers](https://nfs.fandom.com/wiki/Need_for_Speed:_Most_Wanted/Markers). These rewards include cash bonuses, get-out-of-jail cards, extra impound strikes, reclamation of impounded vehicles, and best of all: the title to your opponent's vehicle, in the form of a "pink slip".

While a 2/3 chance of selecting the pink slip reward marker is pretty fair, how could I guarantee that I am awarded my opponents unique vehicle every time?

I found [this exploit](https://www.ign.com/faqs/2007/need-for-speed-most-wanted-pink-slip-exploit-mini-faq-765057) which states the reward markers are not randomized and, for instance, I could choose the first marker to earn Sonny's car (Rival 15), and choose the third reward marker to earn the Baron's car (Rival 10). However, the [wikia article](https://nfs.fandom.com/wiki/Need_for_Speed:_Most_Wanted/Markers) says the rewards are randomized and I don't want to waste my only opportunity on something I can't confirm. In addition to the IGN article referencing the PlayStation 2 version of the game while I play on the Xbox 360 version.

Is there any way to "reroll" reward markers if I select the wrong one? This question can encompass exploits, save scumming, or any other means of guaranteeing I get these unique and highly modified vehicles, ideally without having to redo the difficult race against the Blacklist rival.

Comment: Not applicable to your situation, but I emulated the game on PCSX2. I just used save states before picking the items. The Xbox 360 version is vastly different than the PS2 version though, so I'd be wary of those guides.